# handlers not been set when xml configuration is used for server

Tags: java, jetty

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    <Set name="handler">
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList">
            <Set name="handlers">
                <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
                    <Item>
                        <New id="webAppServer" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                            <Call name="setContextPath">
                                <Arg type="java.lang.String">"/abc"</Arg>
                            </Call>
                            <Call name="setWar">
                                <Arg type="java.lang.String">"D:\project\abc.war"</Arg>
                            </Call>
                            <Call name="setExtraClasspath">
                                <Arg type="java.lang.String">"D:\project\config"</Arg>
                            </Call>
                        </New>


                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <!--<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandle**strong text**r">
                        </New>-->
                        <New id="webAppClient" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                            <Call name="setContextPath">
                                <Arg type="java.lang.String">"/pqr"</Arg>
                            </Call>
                            <Call name="setWar">
                                <Arg type="java.lang.String">"D:\project\pqr.war"</Arg>
                            </Call>
                            <Call name="setExtraClasspath">
                                <Arg type="java.lang.String">"D:\project\config"</Arg>
                            </Call>
                        </New>
                    </Item>
                </Array>
            </Set>
        </New>
    </Set>
</Configure>
```

for creating server the following code is used in the main class ie the embedded jetty

```
Resource fileserver_xml = Resource.newResource("installation/config/jetty-single.xml");
        XmlConfiguration configuration = new XmlConfiguration(fileserver_xml.getInputStream());
        Server server = (Server)configuration.configure();
```

but when i check the handlers in debug mode arent created /arent assigned to server .
Thnx in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

No quotes on the arg values.

Change ones like this

```xml
<Arg type="java.lang.String">"/abc"</Arg>
```

to this

```xml
<Arg type="java.lang.String">/abc</Arg>
```